# change parent file (for including)

Tags: php

i got 3 files that every one of them is in different folders..

A.php , B.php , C.css .

First , i use A.php to import B.php

A.php:

```
include ('second_folder/B.php');
```

second , **i use B.php** to import C.css :

```
include ('second_folder/third_folder/B.php');
```

as you can see , i had to write down "second_folder" cause of the parent file is A.php.

how can i pass the "parenting" from A.php to B.php that i would can be write in B.php like that:

```
include ('third_folder/B.php');
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: define proper LIB or Class Path eg `define("PATH","/var/www/html/")` then you use include (PATH . "/libB/B.php");

Comment: I agree with Baba, that it is overall more proper way to work with inclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php

And don't forget to http://php.net/manual/en/function.restore-include-path.php

Example:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'second_folder');
```